# How to draw a Fourier spectra for my txt file data on MatLab?

Tags: matlab, fft, spectrogram, continuous-fourier

I have a ground-based magnetic data in txt file taken every second and I want to plot its Fourier Spectra.

And I notice the spectrogram equation on MatLab need this parameters (window, noverlap, nfft, Fs) which I don't know.

And I notice also that I should do the FFT on my data first before plot its spectrogram, but my data is not discrete and FFt for the discrete data, anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: window is the type of windowing option you want to use, it can be a hamming/hanning/blackman/rectangle etc. noverlap stands for number of overlaps which is usually set to 50%, nfft is the number of FFT and Fs is the sampling frequency, if you do not fully understand what these parameters mean, I suggest you google them, as they are very important for the correct output of your data ESPECIALLY because you have low sampling frequency, which may lead to spectral leakage.

Answer (score 0):

data is discrete by definition.  `spectrogram` and `fft` give different view s of the data.

`spectrogram` would be appropriate for a STFT short-time Fourier transform, in case you want to look at successive, overlapping windows of time. `fft` is the method `spectrogram` will use to compute the transform.

. `Fs` is the sampling rate, which  you say is  once per second, so 1 Hz. Here is one way to view the spectrum,

```
Fs = 1;
X = fft(data);
N = length(data);
freq = (-N/2:N/2 - 1)*Fs/N;
XmagdB = 10*log10(X.*conj(X));
plot(freq, XmagdB)
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for answering. I applied your code and i got this plot ( https://www.flickr.com/photos/51475975@N07/20491245828/in/dateposted-public/ ) and i want spectrogram of the data.